# C#: Storage of instances in the class; get NullReferenceException when trying to get theirs value

Tags: c#, oop, nullreferenceexception

I am a new to OOP and C#. Here is a small experiment I made:

```cs
Using System;
class A
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public static A[] a = new A[10];
    public static int i = 0;
    public A()
    {
        this.X = -2;
    }
    public A(int x)
    {
        this.X = x;
    }
    public static void Add(A b)
    {
        if (i < 10) a[i] = b;
        i++;
        return;
    }
    public void Reveal()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(X);
    }
    public static void Show()
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=10; ++j)
        {
            a[j].Reveal();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried creating a class that has its instances stored inside, up to 10 objects. When invoke the `A.Show()` a NullReferenceException is thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." As I guess, it must be the object `a[j]` is created, then destroyed immediately. So it give `a[j]` a null value, hence the result? 
*This is my `main` method:

```
int val = 0;
while (val != -1)
{
    Console.Write("create a new object. new value: ");
    val = Console.ReadLine();
    A a = new A(val);
    A.Add(a);
 };
 A.Show();
 Console.ReadKey();
 return;
```

Comment: `j<=i` should be `j<i`

Comment: Oh, it should have been `j < 10`. And then if the instances exists for a whole time, it must print out `-2`

Answer (score 2):

Please pay attention to the upper bound condition of the loop:

```
 for (int j=0; j<=10; ++j)
    {
        a[j].Reveal();
    }
```

array a has 10 items assigned,but this code shows you have 11 items beginning from 0 to 10, so change it to just lower than 10.And also try to compare
So the correct code can be as follows :

```
  public static void Show()
         {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            a[j]?.Reveal();//Or if(a[j] != null)
        }
    }
```

and also make amendment to line that reads the input of client,that must be as follow:

```
      val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//If you are sure that the input
```

is truly convertible to int,or

```
       int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine() , out int value);
            if(value != 0)
            {
                val = value;
                A a = new A(val);
                A.Add(a);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing `i` before assigning `a[i]`, so `a[0]` is null because it will always start initializing `a` at 1.

Try changing the add method to this:

```
public static void Add(A b)
{
    if (i < 10)
    {  //braces are important for readability
        a[i] = b;
    }
    i++;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Well,  I tried, but the result is still catastrophic.

Comment: `@Logan` yeah. That damn NullRef.

Comment: Ok, can you post your main method?